# Input to DecodeRaw is not a multiple of 8, the size of double

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I want to build a tensorflow dataset from tfrecords.
this is my code:

```
def make_dataset():
   filenames = [train_tfrecords_dir + name for name in os.listdir(train_tfrecords_dir)] 
   dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(filenames)

    def parser(record):
         keys_to_features = {
        "mhot_label_raw": tf.FixedLenFeature((), tf.string, default_value=""),
        "mel_spec_raw": tf.FixedLenFeature((), tf.string, default_value=""),
    }
        parsed = tf.parse_single_example(record, keys_to_features)

        mel_spec1d = tf.decode_raw(parsed['mel_spec_raw'], tf.float64)
        mhot_label = tf.decode_raw(parsed['mhot_label_raw'], tf.float64)
        mel_spec = tf.reshape(mel_spec1d, [30, 65,85])
        return {"mel_data": mel_spec}, mhot_label

   dataset = dataset.map(parser)
   dataset = dataset.repeat(num_epochs)
   dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size)
   iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
   return iterator
```

but it causes this error:

```
 InvalidArgumentError: Input to DecodeRaw has length 165750 that is not a multiple of 8, the size of double
     [[Node: DecodeRaw = DecodeRaw[little_endian=true, out_type=DT_DOUBLE](ParseSingleExample/Squeeze_mel_spec_raw)]]
     [[Node: IteratorGetNext = IteratorGetNext[output_shapes=[[?,30,65,85], [?,?]], output_types=[DT_DOUBLE, DT_DOUBLE], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](OneShotIterator)]]
```

How could I fix it? I have removed  **tf.decode_raw**  but it didn't work

Answer (score 1):

Because you use tf.decode_raw to convert your image to double(tf.float64) type, which's size is 8 bytes. so the parsed['mel_spec_raw'] should be a multiple of 8. You can print the type of **parsed['mel_spec_raw']**, it should be **tf.string**, which explain why the size of the parsed['mel_spec_raw'] is 165750. Your can change your code to:

```
# mel_spec1d = tf.decode_raw(parsed['mel_spec_raw'], tf.float64)
mel_spec1d = tf.decode_raw(parsed['mel_spec_raw'], tf.uint8)
```

it might work, because of the size of tf.uint8 is only 1. If you want to convert the type into tf.float64, you can convert the type into tf.float using tf.cast

```
mel_spec1d = tf.cast(mel_spec1d, tf.float64)
```

Hope this will help you.